# java/hibernate - how to map three tables/entities with annotation (hibernate error not mapped to a single property)

Tags: java, annotations, hibernate-mapping

Please help!!. There are three tables

```
customer, order,order_details
```

One customer can have many orders and one order has one customer.
One order can have many order details and one order detail has one order.

Following my classes.

OrderDetail.java

```
@Entity
public class OrderDetail {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderDetail_PK orderDetail_PK;

    private int qty;
    private double unitPrice;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="itemCode", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Item item;
    ...
    ..
```

OrderDetail_PK.java

```
 @Embeddable
public class OrderDetail_PK implements Serializable{

    private String orderId;
    private String itemCode;
..
..
```

Order.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="`Order`")
public class Order { 

    @EmbeddedId
    private Order_PK order_PK;

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerId", referencedColumnName = "customerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = new ArrayList<>();
..
..
```

Order_PK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Order_PK implements Serializable{

    private String Id;
    private String customerId;
..
..
```

cusotomer.java

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customerId")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();
..
..
```

What is wrong with my code? I need quick help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thank you for response Michael,
The error is  "
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of pos.entity.OrderDetail.order referencing pos.entity.Order not mapped to a single property"

Comment: The problem is that you are using composite keys (`EmbeddedId`). You need to provide multiple `JoinColumn`s by using `@JoinColumns`.

Comment: Thank you Michael , I am new for hibernate. Can you give me some example in my code please

Comment: See my answer I have posted.

Comment: I'm checking, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using composite keys, you need to define all relevant join columns:

```
@Entity
public class OrderDetail {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="orderId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="customerId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    })
    private Order order;
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I'v got new error "Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Column name customerId of pos.entity.Order not found in JoinColumns.referencedColumnName"

Comment: Try `@JoinColumn(name="customerId", referencedColumnName = "customerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Comment: It's fix exceptions. But Final result is'n what i expected. CustomerID not insert to order table. added customerID column to orderdetails table. That is not what i expected.

Comment: `OrderDetail` needs the `customerId` because it is part of the composite primary key of `Order` (orderId, customerId).

Comment: It would be much easier to make `orderId` the PK of `Order`. But apparently you need `customerId` for uniqueness. I don't know your exact requirements. Please elaborate. ;)